# Google Keep auto-focuses Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-keep

I opened Google Keep in Google Chrome, then I focused another window while it was loading.  Suddenly, Chrome re-focused itself!  While I was typing in another window!  (I even minimized the window, and it un-minimized it)

How does it do this and how can I turn it off?  I didn't think browsers let you do that with JavaScript.  Is it an extension or something built-in to Chrome?

I made a quick screencast.  Here's a video of what is happening: http://youtu.be/6zcVbqpHciM

Comment: It's not happening in my case. Can you share more details like OS,browser version etc etc. I don't think browsers can do that. It might be some extensions or settings

Comment: @KK: Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 m on Windows 7.  I don't have extensions that would be doing this (I don't think).

Comment: Strange! Is there any way to reproduce it? Does it happens often?

Comment: @KK: I can repro it every time.  1) Open Chrome, 2) Open https://drive.google.com/keep/, 3) Minimize Chrome, 4) ???, 5) Chrome mazimizes itself.  Let me see if I can't make a screencast of it

Comment: Found this thread: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-x64-pro-window-focus-issueswhen-i-open-a/a55aec2b-ee7e-40f2-bc8b-8f4728671ca4.  Go through this thread, some of them has similar issues like your but not specifically to Chrome. Maybe it will help you in resolving the issue

Comment: @KK: Check this YouTube video of the issue: http://youtu.be/6zcVbqpHciM